# How do I assign a pointer to a record element using an existing pointer?

Tags: pointers, delphi

I understand the concept of pointers and how to use, but I just want to clear up a bit of confusion in my head about assigning a pointer to a record sub-element already pointed to by another pointer...

I've seen some questions elsewhere that are I think asking the same thing, but the answers are in C...

If I have:

```
type
  TDetails = record
     Name : string;
     Origin : string;
  end;

  TMsgData = record
     ID : string;
     Code : integer;
     Details : TDetails;
  end;

var
  MessageData = array of TMsgData;
```

I can obviously get a pointer to specific record of TMsgData type by:

```
var
  pMessageData = ^TMsgData;

begin
  pMessageData := @MessageData[0];
...
```

And of course I can then access all the record elements using that pointer with standard dereferencing.

But, how do I get a new pointer to just the Details record of MessageData[0] using the first pointer? I want to avoid having a pointer to a pointer so if pMessageData is free'd I still have the other pointer.

If I do

```
name := pMessageData.Details.Name;
```

then Delphi will automatically dereference this to give me the value of name. So if I did:

```
var
  pMessageDetails = ^TDetails;

begin
  pMessageDetails = @pMessageData.Details;

*or*

  pMessageDetails = Addr(pMessageData^.Details);
```

Do either of those give me a pointer to a pointer or a new pointer to the original record?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's be pedantic.

`pMessageData` is a pointer to a `TMsgData`. This means that `pMessageData^` is a `TMsgData`, and `pMessageData^.Details` is its `TDetails`.

A pointer to this record is therefore `@(pMessageData^.Details)`, which can also be written `Addr(pMessageData^.Details)` using the [`Addr`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Addr) function.

Furthermore, `@(pMessageData^.Details)` is parsed the same way as `@pMessageData^.Details`, so you can omit the parentheses.

In fact, you can even [omit](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Pointers_and_Pointer_Types_(Delphi)#Using_Extended_Syntax_with_Pointers) the dereferencing operator and write simply `@pMessageData.Details`.

---

Actually, you can easily verify that my conclusions are correct using Delphi itself:

```pascal
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  pMessageData: ^TMsgData;
  p1, p2, p3, p4: ^TDetails;
begin

  SetLength(MessageData, 3);

  MessageData[1].ID := 'Alpha';
  MessageData[1].Code := 123;
  MessageData[1].Details.Name := 'Test';
  MessageData[1].Details.Origin := 'NYC';

  pMessageData := @MessageData[1];

  p1 := @(pMessageData^.Details);
  p2 := Addr(pMessageData^.Details);
  p3 := @pMessageData^.Details;
  p4 := @pMessageData.Details;

  ShowMessage(p1^.Origin);
  ShowMessage(p2^.Origin);
  ShowMessage(p3^.Origin);
  ShowMessage(p4^.Origin);

  ShowMessage(NativeInt(p1).ToString);
  ShowMessage(NativeInt(p2).ToString);
  ShowMessage(NativeInt(p3).ToString);
  ShowMessage(NativeInt(p4).ToString);

  ShowMessage(NativeInt(@MessageData[1].Details).ToString); // same as last four

  ExitProcess(0)

end;
```

Comment: Thanks @Andreas...ive been playing with all those ways to do it and I was trying to work out if one way was better than the other or if one gave a pointer to pointer situation, but it seems that they all give the same result and it doesn't matter what happens to the original pointer.

Comment: @WartH0g: Correct, as you can see by the last tests, all four pointers point to the exact same location in memory, namely, the `Details` member of the second `TMsgData` value in the dynamic array.

Comment: Thats largely the bit I was missing - how to see the actual address so I could verify they are all pointing to the same thing. Your code is very useful, i’ve saved it for future reference.